# Fixed Position content loads on left then jumps to correct position on right

Tags: css, position, fixed

http://dovetailsoftware.redbranchmedia.com/hr/

For my site, I have social icons vertically with fixed positioning on the side of the page. On each page load, the icons load first on the left then jump to the right. Does anyone know why this is happening or how to prevent it? Thanks

Comment: Can you please post some code (HTML/CSS) and give us some insight into what you have already tried?

Comment: On your site I used Chrome's inspector to switch the left and right CSS on the .pullout-button and .pullouts. There are some more styles you have to change to make the icons expand right instead of left but a quick test had the icons load on the left and stay on the left. that is, if you want them on the left. If you want them on the right I can look at it again.

Comment: Thanks for the response and help. Here is a paste of the html in that area: http://pastebin.com/LaJiRVYP

The container is position:fixed with a z-index of 9999 and right:0. The social links inside that container also have fixed positioning with right:0. 

There is a search box and a pop-out phone number which are the .pullouts, but those are loaded in the footer after everything else and are not suffering from the same behavior. It's the Facebook, Twitter, Linkedin, Email, RSS and Info icons which all load on the left initially and then jump to the right. 

Thanks again!

Comment: one clue...  when I disable JavaScript in my browser, the icons start on the left and STAY on the left.

Comment: BTW, is your desired goal to have the icons on the left or the right?

Comment: My desired goal is to have them on the right. I want them to load on the right from the start. Currently, they load on the left and then jump into the correct position. 

Interesting clue about the JavaScript. I'll take a look at the files and see if that's why it's on the left first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not help many as it seems very specific. Basicaly, the inline style "right:0;" was being added to my html via a script. The content loaded by default on the left then, when the script ran, the inline style was added and the content jumped to the right. To fix this, I simply added the CSS to my stylesheet. Now, it loads initially on the right as well.